# Python: Getting if variables contain same string data

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to make a name system for Leaderboard. I have created text files for leaderboard, it fills each text file at the end and reads it in leaderboard.

I also made names as text files, Reason of this is to avoid users inserting same names in text file.

Name System:

User enters name in QLineEdit -- > Click's submit button which connects to main function of name system -- > Name's will be written in Name text files.

---

There is a list variable that reads all the lines in file, In this case i defined it as `data6`.

I have tried this:

```
            for name2 in self.data6:
               if self.name.text() in name2:
                print "True"
```

Got the error:

`TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not QString`

Tried this too:

```
for name2 is self.data6:
           if self.name.text() in name2:
            print "True"
```

But statement was false.

```
for name2 == self.data6:
           if self.name.text() in name2:
            print "True"
```

Statement was false on this boolean either.

`self.name.text()` is QLineEdit variable, `name2` is first row variable in data6 (Array variable that reads all lines in name file)

How can i get if `self.name.text()` and `name2` contain same data so i can disallow same names in file.

Or may it be problem of PyQt, in first code, "QString".

Comment: Just wrap the `QString` in `str` to convert to python string.

Comment: Yes thats what i exactly did now and it worked, Thanks!

Comment: @PaulRooney. Converting using `str` is buggy. Always convert using `unicode` so that non-ascii characters are handled correctly.

Comment: @ShellRox. Why are you using Python2 to develop a new application? If you used Python3, you would never have to deal with issues like converting `QString`.

Comment: Actually python2 is very good for developing applications since its shorter and more comfortable for me.

Comment: @ekhumoro  thanks for the info. I wasn't convinced it was the bulletproof was to do it. So I only left a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my problem by converting `QString` to `str`.

```
        for name2 in self.data6:
           if str(self.name.text()) in name2:
            print "True
```

Comment: It may be more efficient to do the conversion before the loop. So that you dont needlessly repeat the same conversion for each loop iteration. It probably wont make any difference but worth mentioning.

Comment: The correct way to deal with this issue is to put `import sip; sip.setapi('QString', 2)` at the beginning of your application. This will automatically convert any`QString` to a python string, so you never have to do the conversions yourself.